# Trouble re-opening Kivy app on Android

Tags: android, python-2.7, kivy, buildozer

I was able to successfully package a Kivy app for Android using Buildozer.  However, I am seeing some problems on the android side.  For example, when I close the app, I can't re-open it for a while.  It just shows a blank screen (black with lighter color at the bottom).  I'm using the home button to put it into pause mode, then using the task manager to close it.  Here is a short example which also displays the same behavior.  It shows different
fonts from .ttf files which were copied into a local folder.  It works fine on Android, just can't close and re-open unless I wait a long while.

main.kv:

```
<MainScreen>:
    Button:
        id: fontbutton
        font_size: 100
        text: 'press here'
        on_press: root.updatebutton()
```

main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class MainScreen(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.i = 0
        self.fontarray = ['Waree', 'Umpush', 'TlwgTypo', 'TlwgTypist',\
            'TlwgMono', 'Sawasdee', 'Purisa', 'Norasi', 'Loma',\
            'Laksaman', 'Kinnari', 'Garuda']

    def updatebutton(self):
        if self.i >= 12: self.i = 0
        self.ids.fontbutton.text = str(self.fontarray[self.i])
        self.ids.fontbutton.font_name = 'usethesefonts/' \
           + str(self.fontarray[self.i]) + '.ttf'
        self.i = self.i + 1

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        themainscreen = MainScreen()
        return themainscreen

if __name__=="__main__":
     MainApp().run()
```

Versions I'm using:  Kivy 1.10.0, Python 2.7.15rc1, Cython 0.23, Buildozer 0.34, Oracle VM Virtualbox Linux, Ubuntu (64-bit) Release 18.04 (bionic)

Here is the uncommented info from my buildozer.spec:
[app], title = sf2, package.name = sfont2, package.domain = org.test, source.dir = ., version = 1, requirements = kivy, orientation = all, osx.python_version = 2, osx.kivy_version = 1.10.0, fullscreen = 1, android.minapi = 13, [buildozer], log_level = 2, warn_on_root = 1

I've been stuck on this problem for a while.  Would appreciate any help I could get.  Thanks!

Comment: rather than directly run your app, you should keep an instance of it try this:`app = MainApp()` then `if __name__=="__main__":app.run()`

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried it, but get the same problem.  I should mention that on my kindle it works fine.  This issue is on my Android phone.